# IE6 double padding and margin bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I was looking around the net and nothing works.

I have a box with an unorderd list and ie6 makes the padding and margin double size

```
.block {
    width: 236px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    background: url(images/list_bg.png) repeat-y;

}

.block li {
        width: 237px;
        height: 74px;
        background: url(images/arrow.png) no-repeat 0px 13px, url(images/bottom.png) left bottom no-repeat;
        margin-left: 30px;
        padding: 0px 20px;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 36px;

    }
```

if i add display inline it breaks, what do im doing wrong?

Comment: I feel sorry for you. 2011 and still debugging IE6.

Comment: Does your code have a valid doctype as the first line, such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`? If it's not that, what is it?

Comment: I honestly think the answer should be:  don't use IE6.

Comment: I agree with @Dave and @edwin -- IE6 has lost virtually all its remaining market share in the last 12 months. There's pretty much no-body using it any more. There really isn't any point supporting it. And if a client/boss does insist on IE6 support, tell them that it'll double the costs of developing and maintaining the web site; see if they still want to support it.

Answer (score 3):

Your box is narrower than the list item inside of it.

You should have a look at the [Box Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)

[image: box model]

Comment: Note that this only applies if IE is in Quirks Mode. From the link you posted: `"Internet Explorer 6 and newer are not affected in their standards-compliant mode, but for compatibility reasons, the bug is still present when a page is rendered in "quirks mode"."`. I've asked the OP if he has a valid doctype, so we'll be able to see if this is the cause.

Comment: @thirtydot: Yeah, of course you're right about the quirks mode bug.
 
In all honesty I linked to the wikipedia page just so the OP would get a greater understanding of the Box Model.

However the parent container is still 1px less wide than it's child.... To me, the box should have a width of 307px.

Comment: +1, you're right about the `width`. I didn't see the OP's "it worked" comment.

Answer (score 0):

some times ie6 will take double margin , 
Read  http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html

we can manage this issue  with ie hack code
ie6  _ , ie  >

```
.class {_margin-left: 30px;}

.class {>margin-left: 30px;}
```